# DatePicker display format display differently

Tags: ios, swift, date, swiftui, picker

I have tried to include a DatePicker in my form. However, it have different behaviour.

```
DatePicker("Date", selection: $selectedDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]).datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
```

I choose different dates, and the display is different:

[image]

[image]

How can I restrict it to display the format shown as April 1, 2021?